# Android - iOS increase build version azure devops (mobile buildtask by montemagno)

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to use the Montemagno extensions 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-473885.motz-mobile-buildtasks
in my azure devops to increase build number and I get the following error

```
Agent job - Failed
Bump Android Versions in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Mobile-Xamarin.Android-CI/HelloWorld-drop/com.myCompany.HelloWorld.apk.mSYM/manifest.xml 
failed
1 error
unable to find the matched key.
```

The first question I have **I could not find my "AndroidManifest.xml**" file but nothing was there the only thing was "Manifest.xml"

Is this the problem? why Could I not see my AndroidManifest file.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set android manifest to copy always and then I could see it .Solved